# Error: Cannot find module '@vue/babel-preset-jsx'

Tags: vue.js

as usual, use npm run serve ，
But suddenly this prompt appeared today

I use vue-cli4
[image]

Comment: Have you already run: "npm install" ?

Comment: of course ，But it doesn't work

Comment: I have resolve it ,change babel.config.js to .babelrc